# Parse Json with different type of inner array

Tags: json

I have a great problem for parse a very difficult json string. For Eg

```
{
    "facilityDetails": [
        {
            "tableName": "FACILITY",
            "facilityDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "itemId": "s101",
                    "name": "facility",
                    "status": 1,
                    "lastEditedOn": "01/Jan/201200: 00: 00.000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tableName": "PLACE_SERVICE",
            "facilityDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "itemId": "22",
                    "name": "placeservice",
                    "facility": "5",
                    "status": 1,
                    "lastEditedOn": "01/Jan/201000: 00: 00.000"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "itemId": "55",
                    "name": "placeservice",
                    "facility": "t",
                    "status": 2,
                    "lastEditedOn": "01/Jan/201000: 00: 00.000"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "itemId": "99",
                    "name": "placeservice",
                    "facility": "r",
                    "status": 33,
                    "lastEditedOn": "01/Jan/201000: 00: 00.000"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "itemId": "22",
                    "name": "placeservice",
                    "facility": "",
                    "status": 0,
                    "lastEditedOn": "01/Jan/201000: 00: 00.000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tableName": "AGENT",
            "facilityDetails": [
                {
                    "agentId": 2,
                    "itemId": "1",
                    "name": "agent",
                    "defUnitId": 0,
                    "defRouteId": 0,
                    "color": "",
                    "synonyms": "",
                    "administrationType": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "lastEditedOn": "01/Jan/201200: 00: 00.000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

for this json string "facilityDetails" is an inner array that have different details at each time. How can i parse this type of json. If anyone know please help me

Comment: Is it possible to use a dictionary. If possible how can i read data from that dictionary. Because it is not necessary that each time i am getting the same  json. Because some time json include only 1 facility details but in some time more that 30 details array. Becuse this data we are taiking from the data base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to parse this with the Json.NET library.

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx